# How to appcompat-v7 make work with api level 17

Tags: android

I am using API level 17 and want to use Appcompat-V7 in my project but after importing, i am facing error saying " No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'" on line

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
           parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
 </style>
```

I have tried to change the target sdk version from 17 to 21 in project.properties file but did not get rid from this error.
If using Api level 17, it is possible to use appcompat-v7 then tell me how?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For Android Studio/Gradle, set your `compileSdkVersion` to match the version of the `appcompat-v7` library. So, if you are using `appcompat-v7:23.1.0`, set `compileSdkVersion` to 23.

Comment: i am using eclipse not android studio

Comment: I strongly suggest that you move to Android Studio before the end of the year, ideally sooner. I have not used Eclipse in over a year, but Project > Properties > Android, then check the build target matching your `appcompat-v7` version, should work IIRC.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will move on soon. 
Actually i am little confused that how may i know the version of appcompat-v7?
Is  sdk platform tools version number will be it's version number ?

Comment: After navigation to  Android i found two options Android 2.2 & 4.2.2. After selecting 4.2.2, i  cleaned my project but still facing same error. !!

Comment: "i am little confused that how may i know the version of appcompat-v7?" -- there is no good way to determine that, given that you are using out-of-date tools. The error is coming from something in API Level 21 (Android 5.0), so you need it to be at least that high, and I suggest taking it all the way to 23 (Android 6.0).

Comment: ohh!
You mean to say that i should install Api level 23 & 21 packages or only 23?

Comment: That is up to you. I do not know what version of the `appcompat` stuff you are using. If you just added it to your project today, and you are on the latest-and-greatest Android Support Library from the SDK Manager, then you probably need 23.

Comment: I have Android SDK Platform Tools 23.0.1 installed for my project. So, I should install direct api level 23 packages for this ?
Am i right ?

Comment: I am really thankful to you for giving me your precious time. please just tell me one thing that on which thing appcompat version depends?